# Execute a method Kafka Callback

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a RestController which calls KafkaSendMethod() to send message to Kafka MQ

```
 @RestController
@RequestMapping("string-rest")
public class SimpleBookRestController {

   @Autowire
    private KafkaSendClass kafkaSendClass;
    
    @GetMapping( produces = "application/json")
    public void postMethod() {
    
    ArrayList<String> gfg = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    gfg.add("a"); 
    gfg.add("b"); 
    gfg.add("c");
    
    kafkaSendClass.KafkaSendMethod(gfg);
    
    }
```

Here is the class which sends message to Kafka

```
@Service
    class KafkaSendClass
    {
    
    @Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;


    void KafkaSendMethod(List<Strings> strList)
    {
    
    for ( String str : strList )
    (
    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String,String>>   future = kafkaTemplate.send(str , str );
    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {
    
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
            syso("sent success");
            m1(); //call only once for one call to KafkaSendMethod() ;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            System.out.println(" sending failed");
        }
    });
```

);
So my question is how do i call m1() once for every  call to KafkaSendMethod(List strList) call.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking: the GET method is not about posting data to Kafka. Not clear where you get that `List<Books>` since your `getBook()` is empty. You don't show how really you call a `KafkaTemplate` for that `books`. So, please, consider to revise your question with more details and more concise code flow.

Comment: @Artem Bilan i have modified my code/Lets say i am sending List of string to KafkaSendMethod().On i i want to m1() only once on onsucess method.How can i achieve this.

For eg. if i have 3 strings in the list and onSuccess will be invoked 3 times then i need to call m1() method only 1 time.How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can use a `CompletableFuture.allOf(...)`.

Gather those `Future`s into a list and use their `completable()` adaptation. Then call `List.toArray()` for that `CompletableFuture`. The `CompletableToListenableFutureAdapter` to add your final callback.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.I think its similar to what i was thinking.Waiting for all futures to complte using CountdownLatch.

Comment: Yeah... Only a difference that you don't block your thread for that count down. It is going to be executed asynchronously when all the underlying `Futures` are complete.